# How to get the smallest number in a series of items, for each series?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my database, one with projects and another with tickets. I want the first ticket for each project.
Table project has:

- AAA
- BBB
- CCC

Table tickets has:

- AAA-1
- AAA-2
- BBB-2
- BBB-3
- CCC-100
- CCC-101

What I want is a list of the smallest ticket in each project so the result should be AAA-1, BBB-2, CCC-101. Is this possible with sql alone? Do I need a function? 
I have been trying with min and joins but I am not able to mix them properly...

Thanks

Comment: First of all, you should separate the values such as `CCC-101` in two columns: "CCC" (VARCHAR) and `101` (NUMERIC). Do this in the database. Then the query becomes very simple.

Comment: How do the two tables relate? Shouldn't the tickets table have one column that stores the project id?

Comment: That is not an advisable way to link those two entities. Project should be a foreign key on the Ticket table.

Comment: I put the information like that to be more simple but tickets table ticket is divided in the varchar and the numeric. And as other people say they relate to the projects by ID. I did not think that information is relevant. How does it make more simple to have it in two columns (Because I already have it like that in my database I did think it would matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly the simplest method is:

```
select concat(substring_index(ticket, '-', 1), , '-',
              min(substring_index(ticket, '-', -1) + 0)
             ) as first_ticket
from t
group by substring_index(ticket, '-', 1)
```

This reconstructs the value after taking the `min()` as a number.

If you don't want to reconstruct the value:

```
select (select t.ticket
        from tickets t
        where t.ticket like concat(p.project, '-%')
        order by length(ticket), ticket
        limit 1
       ) as first_ticket
from projects p;
```

This uses just string operations for the minimum value, so it assumes that there is no zero-padding.   It could be modified to use numbers as well:

```
        order by p.project, substring_index(ticket, '-', -1) + 0
```

Comment: Thanks!! The second query was the one that put me in the right path!